# Will I be able to expand Synology later without losing data with regular RAID

Tags: raid, storage, software-raid, network-attached-storage, synology

I just got Synology 918+ and bought 2x10 TB Hard drives. Before I set up, I just want to avoid getting into trouble in the future.

I don't want to use SHR (Synology hybrid raid) because of several reasons like migrating HDDs to a non-Synology nas, better speed etc. 
So I am planning to go with regular RAID (RAID 1 with 2x10TB HDD) configuration for now.

As 918+ has 4 bays and I am currently using 2 bays right now. 
My question is, will I able to add another one (or even two) 10 TB HDD (Same manufacturer, type size) later and go from RAID 1 (right now) to RAID 5 or RAID 6 in the future without losing the data if I go with non-SHR (regular RAID 1) configuration right now?

Is regular RAID is expandable with Synology?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can both add storage *and* change the RAID type on a Synology NAS. To change the volume RAID, per the instructions from the [official Synology website](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_change_raid_type):

> 1. Open Storage Manager.
> 2. Go to Storage Pool.
> 3. Select the storage pool you wish to change and click Change RAID Type from the Action drop-down menu.
> 4. Select the RAID type to which you want to change the storage pool. Click Next.
> 5. Select which drive to add to the existing storage pool. Then click Next.
> 6. Follow the instructions of the wizard to finish. Please note existing data on the added drive shall be deleted.

Make sure you read the page I linked in detail to ensure that your precise migration path is supported before you set up your initial volume.

Answer (score -3):

Unless you are dealing with Enterprise-grade storage, for most consumer-level NAS the general rule of thumb is that RAIDs are not expandable. If you decide to obtain more HDDs for the Synology NAS, the ideal way to 'expand' your storage is to

- backup all your data from the RAID-1 volume,
- delete that RAID-1 volume,
- create a new RAID-5 storage volume,
- and then copy all the data from the backup to the new RAID-5.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just flat out untrue. I've been using consumer-level NAS's since the word NAS was barely known and it's been about 15 years since I saw one that didn't support online expansion